# How do you use GdkRectangle to determine whether you size-allocate is growing or shrinking?

Tags: scroll, gtk, gdk

I have a callback for the `size-allocate` signal on my GtkScrolledWindow.  I want to scroll to the right when I am adding stuff to that window.  This works fine but introduces a subtle bug when removing items from that window.  I would like to only scroll the window when adding stuff.  I see the signal receives a GdkRectangle but I am unsure how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

First **size-allocate** signal **run-first**, that means, If I'm not wrong, before the default handler. So you can get the **GdkRectangle** of the widget with [gtk_widget_get_allocation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-allocation), and compare it with the new one.
Now **GdkRectangle** is a **cairo_rectangle_int_t** and the definition of that is:

```
typedef struct {
    int x, y;
    int width, height;
} cairo_rectangle_int_t;
```

So you can check width and heights, with the old ones.